# How to write an SQL query that allots a limited number of positions, based on criteria of different precedence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a page where I can view students' applications to dormitories. You can preview it at: http://formularz.funpic.de/dormitory.htm. I'm looking for help writing queries to fetch the information shown on the page. Rooms should be given first to poor students, then to those that live far away from a dormitory. I have 3 dormitories: "lubel", "mleczko", "maryks"

My current database query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM aplication 
  WHERE (sex='w' AND preference1='lubel') 
  GROUP BY poor DESC, distance DESC 
UNION ALL SELECT * 
  FROM aplication 
  WHERE (sex='w' AND preference2='lubel' AND poor='') 
  GROUP BY distance DESC  
UNION ALL SELECT * 
  FROM aplication 
  WHERE (sex='w' AND preference3='lubel' AND poor='') 
  GROUP BY distance DESC
```

I would like to add limits to this query:

- for lubel: 12 places
- for mleczko: 13 places
- for maryks: 5 places

How can I write the query to get such results? I know that I can use `LIMIT` to limit the number of results, but is there any way to ensure that the results have no redundancies?

Comment: Can you add some same sample source data and your desired result set based on that data?

Answer (score 1):

You can make this dramatically easier by separating the `(preference1, preference2, preference3)` into separate tables — what we call "normalization".

If possible, you should create tables something like these:

```
CREATE TABLE application (application_id ... PRIMARY KEY, sex ..., poor ...);
CREATE TABLE preference (application_id ..., dorm ..., rank ...);
```

Now for each `application` you'll have three rows in the `preference` table: one with `rank = 1`, one with `rank = 2`, and one with `rank = 3`.

It may not be possible for you to permanently change the structure, in which case you can do the same thing temporarily with a `TEMPORARY TABLE`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE preference (...)
INSERT INTO preference (SELECT application_id, preference1, 1 FROM application);
INSERT INTO preference (SELECT application_id, preference2, 2 FROM application);
INSERT INTO preference (SELECT application_id, preference3, 3 FROM application);
```

With that in place, the query is simple:

```
SELECT application.*
FROM application
INNER JOIN preference ON (preference.application_id = application.application_id)
WHERE sex = 'w' AND dorm='lubel' AND poor=''
ORDER BY rank, poor DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 12
```

But you asked for more than that: to actually sort everyone at once.

For that, I suggest adding a new `assignment` column (again this can be done temporarily if necessary), so with a series of four queries you can do:

```
UPDATE application SET assignment = NULL

UPDATE application.*
INNER JOIN preference ON (preference.application_id = application.application_id)
SET assignment = 'lubel'
WHERE assignment IS NULL AND sex = 'w' AND dorm='lubel' AND poor=''
ORDER BY rank, poor DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 12

UPDATE application.*
INNER JOIN preference ON (preference.application_id = application.application_id)
SET assignment = 'mleczko'
WHERE assignment IS NULL AND sex = 'w' AND dorm='mleczko' AND poor=''
ORDER BY rank, poor DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 13

UPDATE application.*
INNER JOIN preference ON (preference.application_id = application.application_id)
SET assignment = 'maryks'
WHERE assignment IS NULL AND sex = 'w' AND dorm='maryks' AND poor=''
ORDER BY rank, poor DESC, distance DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Note that each time you're finding only people who do not already have an assignment, so once someone gets their choice the assignment column is filled and they won't match any future queries.

I'm assuming that anyone can get any dorm (i.e., everyone has a preference for all three dorms; it's just a question of what order those preferences are).